# stop chef nodes from checking in

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm changing the way my chef cookbooks are managed and would like to stop my nodes from checking in for a bit while I do some updates and test some things.

Is there an easy way to stop my nodes from checking in every 30 min, and then reactivate them later to continue to check in every 30 min?

Comment: Is logging in via SSH to deactivate/activate an option? Otherwise might be hard, if you can't tell the chef-client, when exactly it should check in next.

Comment: well, shouldn't I be able to execute a `knife ssh` command to all the nodes to deactivate their checkin...and then execute the reverse command when I want them to start checking in again?

Comment: Yes, sure. Then the question is, how your chef-client is executed. As a service or through cron? For the first option, `knife ssh "*:*" service chef-client stop` should help, shouldn't it?